# Theorem regarding primitives and complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

In order to apply this theorem must $f$ be continuous in the entirety of the open set $\Omega$ or only on the curve $\gamma$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption of continuity is in the first clause, before "and". The curve $\gamma$ is introduced in the second clause. Therefore, continuity is assumed in $\Omega$.

By the way: the assumption of continuity is redundant here, because having a primitive $F$ implies it. Indeed, $F$ is complex-differentiable, hence infinitely smooth, hence so is $f=F'$.